# Regular Expression Syntax

Tags: java, regex

I need to find two types of instances when there is a "[" character using regular expressions:

1. When the "[" character is followed by a number.
2. When the "[" character is followed by letters.

In Java I have tried:

```
Pattern firstinstance = Pattern.compile("\\[abcdefgABCDEFG");
Pattern secondinstance = Pattern.compile("\\[[0-9]");
```

These however, don't really seem to work. Do you guys have any possible suggestions?

Comment: Homework is it? if so you should add homework to the tags.  meanwhile i'll give you the answer below.

Comment: Did you even try to google for a regex tutorial? I just did and found everything you asked for.

Comment: "Do you guys have any possible suggestions?" - Yea.  Read a tutorial or textbook on regexes.  It will help you answer this question for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first instance is when the "[" character is followed by a number.

Any decimal digit in any script:

```
"\\[\\p{Nd}"
```

Any digit in 0-9 only:

```
"\\[\\d"
"\\[[0-9]"
```

---

> The second instance is when the "[" character is followed by letters.

Any letter in any script:

```
"\\[\\p{L}"
```

Only letters in A-Z or a-z:

```
"\\[[A-Za-z]"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern firstinstance = Pattern.compile("\\[[a-zA-Z]+");
Pattern secondinstance = Pattern.compile("\\[[0-9]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern first = Pattern.compile("[[][0-9]");
Pattern second = Patter.compile("[[][A-z]+");
```

Regular expressions are very simple to understand.  Have a look at [Basic Concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts%5d)

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you need to escape your escape characters (this is a consequence of the pattern being defined a string).  So you would use the code

```
Pattern firstinstance = Pattern.compile("\\[[0-9]");
Pattern secondinstance = Pattern.compile("\\[[a-zA-Z]");
```

Those strings are read as

```
\[[0-9]
```

and

```
\[[a-zA-Z]
```

which are the regular expression you want.

Note, to get a literal backslash in the regex you need to use 4 backslashes `\\\\`.